# Automatizar a criação de números em um loop no R

Tags: loop, for, r

Os algarismos após `^` (`1`, `2` e `3`) são os valores que desejo automatizar (de forma crescente: do 1 ao *i-ésimo* valor):

```
var1<-rnorm(3,5000,1300)/1.15^1
var2<-rnorm(3,5000,1300)/1.15^2
var3<-rnorm(3,5000,1300)/1.15^3
```

Mas, automatizar dentro de um loop `for`:

```
for(i in 1:10){
name<-paste0('var',i)
assign(name,rnorm(3,5000,1300)/1.15^1)
}
```

Como inserir esta automatização no loop `for` e evitar escrever uma função por vez?

Comment: Não é simplesmente substituir `1.15^1` por `1.15^i`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando se têm vários objetos semelhantes, a regra geral é tê-los numa `list`. Em vez de ter `n` (neste caso 10) objetos no `.GlobalEnv` tem-se só um.
Para criar essa `list` não é necessário um ciclo `for`, pode ser feito com `lapply`.

```
var_list <- lapply(1:10, function(i) rnorm(10, 5000, 1300)/1.15^i)
names(var_list) <- paste0("var", 1:10)
var_list
```

Isto tem a vantagem de, como têm todos o mesmo comprimento, os podermos transformar em vetores coluna de uma matriz,

```
mat_var <- do.call(cbind, var_list)
mat_var
```

ou de uma `data.frame`.

```
df_var <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, var_list)
df_var
```

Depois podem-se usar as funções R que operam sobre tabelas.

Answer (score 3):

Uma resposta foi dada pelo @Marcus Nunes no campo de comentários. A expressão fica, então:

```
for(i in 1:10){
    name <- paste0('var', i)
    assign(name, rnorm(3, 5000, 1300)/1.15^i)
}
```